# Getting access to PipelineOptions from a CombineFn in Google cloud dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I need to instantiate use a `GcsUtil` from within a `CombineFn` subclass and it looks like I need to hand a PipelineOptions instance to the GcsUtilFactory. However I cannot find a way to retrieve an instance of the `PipelineOptions` class (unlike in `DoFn`s).

Is there an API to retrieve the current pipeline's options at runtime?
Keeping the options in a field doesn't seem to work and blocks the pipeline upload to the dataflow service.

Thanks!
G

Comment: For now I switched to a ParDo/DoFn approach, but there are other contexts when getting the PipelineOptions could be useful.

Comment: Can you provide any details on what you wanted to use GcsUtil for within the CombineFn?

Comment: I need to load a file from gcs that contains properties of the records I'm processing. I know that I can load it elsewhere - but that would mean carrying along a complex record up to the point where these extra properties are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading from GCS within the CombineFn is likely to be problematic. For instance, you wouldn't get any of the caching that side-inputs give you.

Depending on what kind of configuration you're trying to do, your best bet is probably to use a ParDo/DoFn before running the Combine.

Separately, it probably does make sense for PipelineOptions to be made accessible from within the CombineFn. I've made a note of this, and we'll take a look.